# How to calculate the number of columns got changed by comparing two tables with column names in sql

Tags: sql

How to calculate the number of columns got changed by comparing two tables with same column names based on joining key 'id' in sql.

```
Table 1
id val1  val2  val3  val4
1   a    b    c    d
2   d    f    k    e
4   r    t    y    u

Table 2
id val1 val2 val3 val4
1   a    h    c    l
2   d    f    k    e
4   g    a    w    u

count:
id  count
1    2
2    0
4    3
```

I want this count variable to be added to the second table at last and give the count of how many values got changed from previous table to this.

Comment: Please use `ctrl+k` tp format code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (id INT, val1 VARCHAR(5),  val2 VARCHAR(5), val3 VARCHAR(5), val4 VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES
(1,'a', 'b','c','d'),
(2,'d', 'f','k','e'),
(4,'r', 't','y','u')

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (id INT, val1 VARCHAR(5),  val2 VARCHAR(5), val3 VARCHAR(5), val4 VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES
(1, 'a','h','c','l'),
(2, 'd','f','k','e'),
(4, 'g','a','w','u')

SELECT T1.id,  
 (CASE WHEN T1.val1 <> T2.val1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 + (CASE WHEN T1.val2 <> T2.val2 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END)
 + (CASE WHEN T1.val3 <> T2.val3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 + (CASE WHEN T1.val4 <> T2.val4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [count]
FROM @Table1 T1 INNER JOIN @Table2 T2
ON T1.id = T2.id
```

or you can use `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT T1.id, SUM (CASE WHEN T1.Val = T2.Val THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) [count] FROM
(SELECT * FROM @Table1 UNPIVOT ( Val FOR Col IN ([val1],[val2],[val3],[val4]) ) UNPVT) T1
    INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM @Table2 UNPIVOT ( Val FOR Col IN ([val1],[val2],[val3],[val4]) ) UNPVT) T2
ON T1.id = T2.id AND T1.Col = T2.Col
GROUP BY T1.id
```

Result:

```
id  count
1    2
2    0
4    3
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. But if i have huge number of columns like 300 or so what should i do?

Comment: You can use `UNPIVOT` to make this.

Comment: Thank You so much for your responses.If i would need get the column names that got changed for each id , what i need to add to this existing code.

Comment: Just add T1.Col to select and group by part of the last query.

Comment: The UNPVT way is not working for me. I am using the first way using all case statements. How to know which columns got changed for each row?

Comment: you can add this case column.  `  (CASE WHEN T1.val1 <> T2.val1 THEN ', val1' ELSE '' END)
 + (CASE WHEN T1.val2 <> T2.val2 THEN ', val2' ELSE '' END)
 + (CASE WHEN T1.val3 <> T2.val3 THEN ', val3' ELSE '' END)
 + (CASE WHEN T1.val4 <> T2.val4 THEN ', val4' ELSE '' END) AS [changed_columns]`

Comment: But the above query giving all zeroes under 'changed_columns' . I think it only giving integer value not of string type.

Comment: The + operator is not working with strings. Can we use concat or some other functions here to append these strings. Please suggest.

Comment: Which database are you using? Mssql, oracle or mysql etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.ID,SUM(CASE WHEN t1.VAL1 <> t2.Val1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                 CASE WHEN t1.VAL2 <> t2.Val2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                 CASE WHEN t1.VAL3 <> t2.Val3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                 CASE WHEN t1.VAL4 <> t2.Val4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID
```